# SciPy LeastSq Failed to Provide Best Solution

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I tried to use Leastsq to fit a very simple curve. However, its solutions are not optimized. Could anyone give me some suggestion?
Below is my code:

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

hl_obs = np.array([10.0, 23.0, 20.0])
ph=np.array([5.0,7.0,9.0])

tp=60

def residuals(k_abn, ph, tp, hl_obs):
        hr=np.log(2)/(hl_obs*24.0)
        ph_adj=6013.79/(tp+273.15) + 23.6521*np.log10(tp+273.15)-64.7013
        err = peval(k_abn, ph, ph_adj)-hr
        return err

def peval(k_abn, ph, ph_adj):
    temp= k_abn[0]*np.power(10,-ph) + k_abn[1] + k_abn[2]*np.power(10,(-ph_adj + ph))
    return temp

k_abn =np.array([1, 0, 0])

from scipy.optimize import leastsq
p,ier = leastsq(residuals, k_abn, args=(hl_obs, ph, tp), maxfev=2000000)
print p, ier
```

From EXCEL's solver, I know the solution should be `k_abn=[165, 0.001237578, 2.14]`. Once I fed Excel's solution to the `function peval`, it generated the right answer...

```
peval([165,0.001238,2.14], 5.0, 13.01573)=0.002888113
peval([165,0.001238,2.14], 7.0, 13.01573)=0.001255701
peval([165,0.001238,2.14], 9.0, 13.01573)=0.001444057
```

In addition, I tried to increase the precision using `epsfcn=np.finfo(np.float32).eps`
Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get args in the right order:

```
p,ier = leastsq(residuals, k_abn, args=(ph, tp, hl_obs), maxfev=2000000)
```

You get the result:

```
[  1.65096852e+02   1.23712405e-03   2.14392540e+00]
```

Comment: Not stupid. This is what progress looks like. At least in my own code, it's always most important to fix the 1+1=3 bugs. Once I've done that, the more sophisticated ones (usually) take care of themselves. It *is* worth spending a little time thinking about what practices you can develop to prevent bugs like this from happening in the future. It won't work in this case (since leastsq won't let you), but passing in named arguments ph=ph,tp=tp, etc is sometimes good even when it's redundant because it prevents errors like this from happening.